# AES Encoding Decoding by java in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I am doing encoding and decoding by use AES algorithm through  WSO2 ESB Class Mediator by creating jar file and deployed to micro-integrator/lib directory ,So i
am getting error **Error occurred while deploying the Carbon application: C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\repository\deployment\server\carbonapps\TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: com.example.AesEncoderDecoder.isContentAware()Z**